# VueJS Vee-validate in Custom Components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate

**Versions**

VueJs: 2.3.3
Vee-Validate: 2.0.0-rc.25
**Description**
I have a custom component. It is a input with a characteres counter, and i tried to put vee-validate inside this input. I want to show errors when Form is Submited. I followed every step in vee-validate document, but it did not work. My form submits itself ignoring any input's error.

**Steps To Reproduce:**
Create a custom component using vee-validate

**CODE:**
***Parent.vue***

```
   <vue-input maxlength="20" minlength="3" placeholder="works"
    validate="required|numeric" v-model="dataItem.teste" name="teste"></vue-input>
```

***Component.js***

```
Vue.component('vue-input', {
    props: ['maxlength', 'minlength', 'placeholder', 'validate', 'value', 'name'],
    template: `<div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" :name="name" :value="value" 
                @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value); 
                counter = $event.target.value.length" 
                :maxlength="maxlength" :placeholder="placeholder" 
                v-validate="validate" 
                :class="{'is-danger': errors.has(name), 'form-control' : true}">

                Erros: {{errors}}
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    {{ maxlength - counter }}
                </span>

                <span v-show="errors.has(name)" class="text-danger m-t-xs">
                    {{ errors.first(name) }}
                </span>
             </div>
             </div>`,
             data: () => ({
                 counter: 0
             })
});
```

Comment: How does your form look like?

Comment: Like this first: https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Character-Counter-In-Text-Fields.jpg

Comment: I mean the layout and component for your form.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the parent `$validator` in the children component.

See `created()` hook in children component:

**Children.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input
          type="text"
          :name="name"
          :value="value"
          @input="handleInput"
          :maxlength="maxlength"
          :placeholder="placeholder"
          v-validate="validate"
          :class="{'is-danger': $errors.has(name), 'form-control' : true}"
      >

      Errors: {{ $errors }}
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        {{ maxlength - counter }}
      </span>

      <span v-show="$errors.has(name)" class="text-danger m-t-xs">
        {{ $errors.first(name) }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Temp',

    props: ['maxlength', 'minlength', 'placeholder', 'validate', 'value', 'name'],

    data: () => ({
      counter: 0
    }),

    methods: {
      handleInput (event) {
        this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
        this.counter = event.target.value.length
      }
    },

    created () {
      this.$validator = this.$parent.$validator
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

```
<children
    maxlength="20"
    minlength="3"
    placeholder="works"
    validate="required|numeric"
    v-model="dataItem.teste"
    name="teste"
></children>
```

---

There are 2 better supported solutions but you need to move the `<span>` with validation in the `Parent.vue` component, because `errors`/`$validator` will **NOT** be available in the `Children.vue` component.

Also, I was **not** able to have multiple input components with the same name in the same form, but you can look into them and test it out:

**Solution 1**

you can use Vue's [provide/inject API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject):

**Children.vue**

```
export default {
  inject: ['$validator'],
  // ...
}
```

**Solution 2**

use VeeValidate's [constructor options](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/custom-component.html):

**Children.vue**

```
export default {
  $_veeValidate: {
    // value getter
    value () {
      return this.value
    },
    // component name getter
    name () {
      return 'children'
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```